# Источники по ajax

Tags: ajax, javascript

Какие лучше посмотреть актуальные источники по ajax на чистом javascript, начиная со среднего уровня и до профи? Я знаю, для новичков есть javascript.ru. Есть различные статьи на эту тему, а мне бы все вместе, лучше с примерами.

Comment: На jquery несложно составить обычный запрос ajax. Меня интересует ajax на чистом javascript и какие-нибудь сложные реализации этой технологии.

Comment: на чистом javascript ajax не бывает. XHR это браузерный диалект.

Answer (score 1):

В ajax нет какого-то уровня. Это (в контексте коммуникации) просто обозначение технологии выполнения самых обычных запросов, включающее в себя спецификцию XHR (ее и читать), CORS и некоторые другие вещи, освоение которых займет дай боже вечер.
Я вообще не понимаю, почему все носятся с этой технологией, как с писаной торбой, будто это отдельный язык программирования.

> обычный запрос ajax

других не бывает

> Меня интересует ajax на чистом javascript

Еще раз, весь аякс (с т.з. яваскрипта) - это один объект XMLHttpRequest (XHR): [1](http://xmlhttprequest.ru/) [2](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest) [3](http://learn.javascript.ru/ajax-xmlhttprequest) [4](http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest/) [5](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/XMLHttpRequest)

> какие-нибудь сложные реализации этой технологии.

Еще раз: градаций сложности не существует

Answer (score 1):

Вот это неплохая книга [AJAX и PHP. Разработка динамических веб-приложений](http://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/2820553/)

Answer (score 0):

По моему мнению один из [лучших туториал](http://kaidez.com/ajax-tutorial/) которые я видел.